# вернуть input type='file' в первоначальное состояние

Tags: javascript

Имеется форма для загрузки файла на сервер в которой множество полей

`<form method="post" action="" id="file-rorm"> ...
<input id="documentscan" type="file" name="documentscan" accept="application/pdf"/> ... </form>`

Если пользователь выбрал файл у себя на компьютере - с помощью JS проверяется его тип и размер

```
document.getElementById("documentscan").addEventListener("change", checkFile);

function checkFile() {                    
var file = document.getElementById("documentscan").files[0];
if (file.type !== "application/pdf") {
alert("Вы пытаетесь загрузить недопустимый файл");
}
else if (file.size > 5212880) {
  alert("Допустимый размер файла до 5МБ");
}}
```

Если выбранный файл не валидный пользователю показывается соответствующие уведомления, но элемент  `<input id="documentscan" type="file" name="documentscan" accept="application/pdf"/>` так и остается с выбраним файлом.

Как сделать reset конкретного input в форме чтоб не ресетить всю форму?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Установить `value` в пустую строку или `null`. В старых браузерах этот вариант вполне может не сработать.

```js
document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("file").value = "";
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input value="Saved value" />
  <input id="file" type="file" />
  <input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

2. Создать `input` и  заменить им существующий. Однако в таком случае будут потеряны все обработчики событий, которые были добавлены на старый `input`.
3. Обернуть `input` в "искусственную" форму, после чего сделать `reset` этой формы и вернуть `input` на место:

```js
document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var file = document.getElementById("file");
    var fileParent = file.parentNode;
    var fileNextSibling = file.nextSibling;
    form.appendChild(file);
    form.reset();
    fileParent.insertBefore(file, fileNextSibling);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input value="Saved value" />
  <input id="file" type="file" />
  <input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

На базе [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24608023/3432401).

Answer (score 1):

Так попробуйте

```
file.value = '';
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("documentscan").value = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Если других полей в форме не много (не в вышеописанном случае), то можно:

1. запомнить значения всех других полей;
2. ресетнуть всю форму `document.getElementById("file-rorm").reset();`
3. вернуть значения других полей обратно.